# Кастомизация формы ActiveAdmin в Rails, добавление

Tags: ruby-on-rails, элементы-управления

Добрый день. Есть проект на Rails 5 с ActiveAdmin.
Имеются сущности "Тест" и "Вопрос". У теста может быть много вопросов.
Стоит задача кастомизировать форму создания теста в ActiveAdmin так, чтобы в ней можно было прикреплять заранее созданные вопросы. Вопросов к тесту может быть не более 10. Уже занятые вопросы не должны быть активны для добавления к другим тестам.
Какими путями это можно решить? На ум приходят такие варианты:

- Select, со множественным выбором (в котором с зажатой клавишей control кликаешь выбранные элементы)
- Список вопросов с чекбоксом возле каждого.

Какие еще элементы html для этого существуют? И как организовать это в
   ActiveAdmin, т.к. при кастомизации его форм используется какой-то
   свой синтаксис.

з.ы. Rails только изучаю.

Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте. Подобные задачи решаются "мультиселектом", который по факту есть селект, в который можно выбрать несколько опций.
Я не уверен что в AA можно сделать это из коробки, но расскажу на примере гема [activeadmin-select2](https://github.com/mfairburn/activeadmin-select2).

```
 form do |f|
   f.inputs "Test" do
     f.input :questions, as: :select2_multiple, collection: Question.available
   end
 end
```

Суть очень простая, что Вы создаете мультиселект и для него предоставляете коллекцию, из который пользователь может выбрать необходимые элементы (в Вашем случае запросы никому не принадлежащие). Логику необходимой коллекции можно вытащить в скоуп `available`.

Чтобы это всё заработало есть 3 варианта, расположены в порядке "правильности":

1. Создать промежуточную табличку, которая будет хранить `test_id` + `question_id`, а связь оформить через `has_many through` Тогда AA сможет корректно создать/редактировать необходимые записи.
2. Создать поле-массив `questions` в модели `Test`. Разумеется что это не rails way.
3. Переписать контроллер AA чтобы он создавал/редактирова то что надо. Весьма грязный вариант, который ещё и багами обзоведётся если форма сложная.